# Responsive layout with elm

Tags: layout, responsive-design, elm

I'm quite new to Elm, I've done a lot of javascript. I'd like start using Elm for a personal project and see how it goes, but I'm not sure how to do responsive layout with Elm.

I think one solution might be to use Elm for all the logic (taking advantage of Elm's architecture) and leave the layout to an external CSS library like Foundation just for the responsive grid. But I don't know if this is the right approach - so how do people solve responsive layout problem in Elm and are there any example implementations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the purists prefer inline styles, but then you have to monitor the signal of screen width, which seems rather excessive. The pragmatists use an external stylesheet like you propose.

That's what i did with https://eu-lobbyists.herokuapp.com/